# How to set the Windows Mobile 6 IME mode (to numbers only)

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-mobile-6, ime

In Windows Mobile 5 one of the following methods works to set an input to numbers only:

// Managed 
InputModeEditor.SetInputMode(textBox, InputMode.Numeric);

// Native Wrapper
InputModeSupport.SHSetImeMode(textBox.Handle, InputModeSupport.SHIME_MODE.SHIME_MODE_NUMBERS);

In Windows Mobile 6, neither works.

How do you set the IME to "Numbers Only" in WM 6.0 / .NET CF 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set IME mode you can use the two methods above, switching based on platform using the SystemSettings class to inform it. If you want to use the SIP instead, you can find the GUID of the WYSIWYG keyboard, or "guess" by enumerating all SIPs and choosing one with "Numeric" in its name. Ultimately though, there is no way to guarantee the numbers only keyboard in code.

Comment: Hi , Is that possible to send characters to currently open text box via IME ? What I am trying to do is that I have Bluetooth module that handles connection between Bluetooth keyboard and windows mobile device , when user press key on Bluetooth keyboard Bluetooth module receive it and send it to currently open text box via IME. You aomment will greatly help me.